# Join not returning correct results

Tags: sql-server

My SQL join not returning the desired output.

**TABLE: [visit_data]**

```
[PAT_ID]
[VISITDATE]
[TBLE_NAME]
[CODE_ID]
```

```
PAT_ID  VISITDATE   TBLE_NAME   CODE_ID
AAA000  1995-05-02  COMSYS_lkup     1
AAA000  1995-05-02  env_lkup        4
AAA000  1995-05-02  env_lkup        3
AAA001  1999-07-07  COMSYS_lkup     5
AAA001  1999-07-07  env_lkup        1
```

**TABLE: [env_lkup]**

```
[env_ID]
[NAME]
```

```
env_ID  NAME
1       air conditioning
2       pollution
3       secondary cigarette smoke
4       dusty air
```

**Desired Output:**

```
PAT_ID  VISITDATE   env_ID  NAME
AAA000  1995-05-02  4       dusty air
AAA000  1995-05-02  3       secondary cigarette smoke
AAA001  1999-07-07  1       air conditioning
```

**SQL:**

```
  SELECT v.[PAT_ID]   
       , v.[VISITDATE]   
       , e.[env_ID]    
       , e.[NAME]   
  FROM [visit_data] v
  LEFT JOIN [env_lkup] e ON e.env_ID = v.CODE_ID
  WHERE v.TBLE_NAME = 'env_lkup'
```

**Resulting Output:**

```
PAT_ID  VISITDATE   env_ID  NAME
AAA000  1995-05-02  NULL    NULL
AAA000  1995-05-02  NULL    NULL
AAA001  1999-07-07  NULL    NULL
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is `d` in  `WHERE d.TBLE = 'env_lkup'`? I only see table Aliases `v` and `e` in your `FROM` clause. As for your `ON` clause. Do you have a `CODE_ID` with a value of `4` that will correspond with a `env_ID` in the `env_lkup` table? Sharing some sample data from these two tables that match your desired results/output would help.

Comment: CODE_ID in visit_table is not equal to 4, so the two tables do not join as you think they do.

Comment: I corrected the alias, it is `v` in ```WHERE v.TBLE_NAME = 'env_lkup'```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback so far. I have added sample data.

Comment: Your code returns your expected results: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d077b97beea057beca6df9c959548617

Comment: @forpas I wish it were the case in SQL Server, I am still getting NULL values

Comment: @DaleK I added some sample data. Thanks!

Comment: @CharlesCasper I have copied your exact data and table structure into SQL Server and its working perfectly as Forpas says. You must have something different.

Comment: You need to post the full table structure including datatypes in case you have a datatype mismatch.

Comment: "My SQL join not returning the desired output" Do you join it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the joining column's data.

```
LEFT JOIN [env_lkup] e ON e.env_ID = v.CODE_ID
```

The only way I could reproduce your result if the ID columns are both varchar() and one of the ID columns has as a leading space in the value.

When one of the id columns are int, SQL Server makes an implicit conversion and the data is returned.

> Type conversion in expression (CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[e].[env_ID],0))
> may affect "CardinalityEstimate" in query plan choice, Type conversion
> in expression (CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[e].[env_ID],0)=[v].[CODE_ID]) may
> affect "SeekPlan" in query plan choice

How I reproduced the undesired results:

```
Declare @visit_data TABLE 
    ([PAT_ID] varchar(6), [VISITDATE] date, [TBLE_NAME] varchar(11), [CODE_ID] varchar(1));
    
INSERT INTO @visit_data
    ([PAT_ID], [VISITDATE], [TBLE_NAME], [CODE_ID])
VALUES
    ('AAA000', '1995-05-02', 'COMSYS_lkup', '1'),
    ('AAA000', '1995-05-02', 'env_lkup', '4'),
    ('AAA000', '1995-05-02', 'env_lkup', '3'),
    ('AAA001', '1999-07-07', 'COMSYS_lkup', '5'),
    ('AAA001', '1999-07-07', 'env_lkup', '1');

Declare @env_lkup TABLE
    ([env_ID] varchar(2), [NAME] varchar(25));
    
INSERT INTO @env_lkup
    ([env_ID], [NAME])
VALUES
    (' 1', 'air conditioning'),
    (' 2', 'pollution'),
    (' 3', 'secondary cigarette smoke'),
    (' 4', 'dusty air');

SELECT v.[PAT_ID]   
       , v.[VISITDATE]   
       , e.[env_ID]    
       , e.[NAME]   
  FROM @visit_data v
  LEFT JOIN @env_lkup e ON e.env_ID = v.CODE_ID
  WHERE v.TBLE_NAME = 'env_lkup';
```

**Result (Leading Space):**

```
PAT_ID  VISITDATE   env_ID  NAME
AAA000  1995-05-02  NULL    NULL
AAA000  1995-05-02  NULL    NULL
AAA001  1999-07-07  NULL    NULL
```

Note: if the spaces are trailing you will get your desired results:

```
INSERT INTO @env_lkup
    ([env_ID], [NAME])
VALUES
    ('1 ', 'air conditioning'),
    ('2 ', 'pollution'),
    ('3 ', 'secondary cigarette smoke'),
    ('4 ', 'dusty air');
```

**Result (Trailing Space):**

```
PAT_ID  VISITDATE   env_ID  NAME
AAA000  1995-05-02  4   dusty air
AAA000  1995-05-02  3   secondary cigarette smoke
AAA001  1999-07-07  1   air conditioning
```

Comment: Casting id columns as int fixed it `ON cast(e.ENVIRON_ID AS int) = cast(v.CODE_ID AS int)`

Comment: @CharlesCasper, if those columns are always going to store an int, can you make the column int instead of casting to int?  There are performance implications of casting on the JOIN, meaning each row in your tables and if you have many rows, it will be slow.

Comment: With casting: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyycnHX1v

Type conversion in expression (CONVERT(int,[e].[env_ID],0)) may affect "CardinalityEstimate" in query plan choice, Type conversion in expression (CONVERT(int,[v].[CODE_ID],0)) may affect "CardinalityEstimate" in query plan choice, Type conversion in expression (CONVERT(int,[e].[env_ID],0)=[Expr1005]) may affect "SeekPlan" in query plan choice